# Is there any integer $x$ such that $2^n$ divides $3^n(x+1)$ for all integers $n$?

Tags: arithmetic-functions

I am wondering whether: $$\exists x \in \mathbb{N}^* / \, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*,\, 2^n\mid 3^n(x+1)$$

I re-wrote it as $$2^n \leq 3^n(x+1)$$
but it doesn't seem like a good approach.
Any ideas?

Comment: The only fixed $x$ would be $x=-1$. There is no positive $x$ valid for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: It must be a positive integer.

Comment: McOussKing... Then since Burde's comment holds, there is no such $n.$

Comment: Obviously, if $2^n|3^n(x+1)$, then $2^n|x+1$. Next question...

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $ 2^n $ is relative prime with $ 3^n $ for each $ n $, necessarily $ 2^n $ divides $ x + 1 $ for each $ n $. Then $ x + 1 $ has infinite different divisors, so $ x + 1 = 0 $, that is $ x = -1 $